# Difficulty completing the snake game with assembly language

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, emu8086

I was able to create a game with assembly language and using the star, which ends like a snake game when it hits the wall, but I want to add another thing to it and that the game ends when the star hits itself. And I have a problem solving part, I wanted you to help.

```
gotoxy macro x,y
     mov dl,x
     mov dh,y
     mov bh,0
     mov ah,2
     int 10h
endm 

printchar macro n
     mov dl,n
     mov ah,2
     int 21h
endm 

printstring macro n
     lea dx,n
     mov ah,9
     int 21h
endm

.model small
.stack 64
.data
    x db 40
    y db 12
    deltax db 0
    deltay db -1 
    msg1 DB "GAME OVER !!!$"
.code
main:            
     mov ax,@data
     mov ds,ax
     gotoxy x,y     
     printchar '*'

     mov ah,7
     int 21h
l1:  
     gotoxy x,y
     mov al,x
     add al,deltax
     mov x,al       
     mov al,y
     add al,deltay
     mov y,al       
     
     gotoxy x,y     
     printchar '*'

     mov ah,0bh     
     int 21h
     cmp al,0     
     je l2          
     mov ah,0
     int 16h        
     cmp al,'w'     
     je L_W
     cmp al,'s'
     je L_S
     cmp al,'a' 
     je L_A
     cmp al,'d'     
     je l_D 
     jmp l2
L_W:                
     mov deltax,0
     mov deltay,-1
     jmp L2
L_S:
     mov deltax,0
     mov deltay,1
     jmp L2
L_A:
     mov deltax,-1
     mov deltay,0
     jmp L2
L_D:
     mov deltax,1
     mov deltay,0
     
L2:     
     cmp y,0      
     je LEND
     cmp y,23
     je LEND
     cmp x,0
     je LEND
     cmp x,79
     je LEND
     jmp l1

LEND:    
     gotoxy 35,12      
     printstring msg1
     mov ah,7
     int 21h
     
     mov ah,4ch
     int 21h
end main
```

[image: picture from run in emu8086]

Comment: You can either track the game state with your own array, or read video memory before writing a character to see if the spot is already drawn.  (e.g. xchg instead of mov store, using direct VGA text access instead of DOS or BIOS char output functions)

Comment: I want to make some changes in the same code that I wrote to add the item I want to the output

Comment: Yeah, obviously.  But you need a whole new data structure, or a change to the I/O, but still keeping (and building on) the logic for what to draw where.  Actually there might be a BIOS function to query the character at the current screen position; if so you could use that.

Comment: Can you help me more?

Comment: I assume this is homework so I'm definitely not going to write it for you (although probably nobody would anyway; too large a missing piece of functionality).  If you have specific questions about how to do something specific, ask that, but Stack Overflow is not a tutoring service, and comments aren't the right place for a back-and-forth tutoring session.  An example of the kind of data structure you might use to track the state of the snake is [Beginner's snake game using PyGame](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/221163) (in Python), but see the answers for ways it could be simpler.

Comment: Related: [The quintessential Snake Game. How to keep track of the snake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66825708) - Sep Roland wrote up a full working version for x86-16 DOS / BIOS, directly accessing VGA RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> printchar macro n
>   mov dl,n
>   mov ah,2
>   int 21h
> endm
> ```

Your *printchar* macro uses the DOS.PrintChar function 02h. For the purpose of your snake game, it's not useful and could sometimes be harmful that this DOS function also emits a carriage return / linefeed. You should use the BIOS.WriteCharacter function 0Ah instead.

```
printchar macro n
  mov cx, 1
  mov bh, 0
  mov al, n
  mov ah, 0Ah  ; BIOS.WriteCharacter
  int 10h
endm
```

### Colliding with a star

To detect a collision all it takes is reading from the video memory using BIOS.ReadCharacterAndAttribute function 08h. You do this right between going to the next position (*gotoxy*) and displaying another star (*printchar*).

```
gotoxy x,y

mov bh, 0
mov ah, 08h   ; BIOS.ReadCharacterAndAttribute
int 10h       ; -> AX
cmp ax, 0720h ; Is this position unoccupied? (0720h means a WhiteOnBlack space character)
jne LEND      ; No

printchar '*'
```

### Crashing into the border

If you would draw the rectangle (0,0) - (79,23), you would not have to verify exceeding the coordinates at label *L2* because the above collision detection would also take care of that.

Next is a quick solution to draw a white rectangle:

```
mov dx, 174Fh  ; (79,23)
xor cx, cx     ; (0,0)
mov bh, 77h    ; WhiteOnWhite
mov ax, 0600h  ; BIOS.ClearWindow
int 10h
mov dx, 164Eh  ; (78,22)
mov cx, 0101h  ; (1,1)
mov bh, 07h    ; WhiteOnBlack
mov ax, 0600h  ; BIOS.ClearWindow
int 10h
```

### One final tip

Be consistent about retrieving a key from the user. Your program mixes the DOS function 07h and the Keyboard BIOS function 00h. I would suggest you use the Keyboard BIOS function all the time.

---

[**edit**]
Your completed code with corrections and even more improvements.
Please note that I have increased the size for the stack. 64 bytes is a bit small and can easily get you into trouble with certain BIOS and/or DOS system calls.

```
gotoxy macro x, y
  mov dl, x
  mov dh, y
  mov bh, 0
  mov ah, 02h     ; BIOS.SetCursor
  int 10h
endm 
    
printchar macro n
  mov cx, 1
  mov bh, 0
  mov al, n
  mov ah, 0Ah     ; BIOS.WriteCharacter
  int 10h
endm
    
printstring macro n
  lea dx, n
  mov ah, 09h     ; DOS.PrintString
  int 21h
endm
    
.model small
.stack 512
.data
  x     db 40
  y     db 12
  delta dw 0FF00h ; deltax = 0  deltay = -1 
  msg1  db "GAME OVER !!!$"
.code
main:            
  mov ax, @data
  mov ds, ax

  mov dx, 174Fh   ; (79,23)
  xor cx, cx      ; (0,0)
  mov bh, 77h     ; WhiteOnWhite
  mov ax, 0600h   ; BIOS.ClearWindow
  int 10h
  mov dx, 164Eh   ; (78,22)
  mov cx, 0101h   ; (1,1)
  mov bh, 07h     ; WhiteOnBlack
  mov ax, 0600h   ; BIOS.ClearWindow
  int 10h

  gotoxy x, y
  printchar '*'
    
  mov ah, 00h     ; BIOS.GetKey
  int 16h         ; -> AX

Again:  
  mov ax, delta
  add x, al
  add y, ah
  gotoxy x, y

  mov bh, 0
  mov ah, 08h     ; BIOS.ReadCharacterAndAttribute
  int 10h         ; -> AX
  cmp ax, 0720h   ; Is this position unoccupied?
  jne Done        ; No

  printchar '*'
    
  mov ah, 01h     ; BIOS.TestKey
  int 16h         ; -> AX ZF
  jz  Again       ; No key available
  mov ah, 00h     ; BIOS.GetKey
  int 16h         ; -> AX
  mov bx, 0FF00h  ; deltax = 0  deltay = -1
  cmp al, 'w'     ; Up
  je  SetDelta
  mov bx, 0100h   ; deltax = 0  deltay = 1
  cmp al, 's'     ; Down
  je  SetDelta
  mov bx, 00FFh   ; deltax = -1  deltay = 0
  cmp al, 'a'     ; Left
  je  SetDelta
  mov bx, 0001h   ; deltax = 1  deltay = 0
  cmp al, 'd'     ; Right
  jne Again
SetDelta:
  mov delta, bx
  jmp Again
    
Done:    
  gotoxy 35, 12
  printstring msg1
  mov ah, 00h     ; BIOS.GetKey
  int 16h         ; -> AX
  mov ax ,4C00h   ; DOS.Terminate
  int 21h
end main
```

Comment: Thank you very much and that it is possible for you to guide me and tell me how to put these codes in my codes?

Comment: @AkbarNasiri The 1st snippet is a simple replacement, the 2nd snippet is an insertion where I told it to go, and the 3rd snippet comes right after `mov ax,@data` `mov ds,ax`.

Comment: Thank you very much sep roland and thank you for your effort

Comment: Thank you my dear friend and thank you very much for your help. I really did not know that I had to do this and I was not familiar with the rules and now I checked the correct answer for all 3 questions but one point and that I did not realize that this part Second, where should I put the code, wherever I put it, it gives an error 'code'  gotoxy x,y mov bh, 0 mov ah, 08h ; BIOS.ReadCharacterAndAttribute int 10h ; -> AX cmp ax, 0720h ; Is this position unoccupied? (0720h means a WhiteOnBlack space character) jne LEND ; No printchar '*' '

Comment: @AkbarNasiri I have updated the answer with an improved version of your program. I hope it works first hand.

Comment: dear sep roland , I wanted to know if this game can be written using arrays? Is it possible at all? Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: @AkbarNasiri Sure, and you're already using an array! The video memory is in fact a 2-dimensional array (aka matrix) that your program currently writes to (BIOS function 0Ah) and reads from (BIOS function 08h). Some programmers will prefer to mirror the screen matrix in regular RAM where reading is much faster.

Comment: @AkbarNasiri Another form of array would be one that records the X,Y coords of all of the segments of the snake so it becomes possible to remove one segment at the tail while adding a new segment at the head. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094373/snake-in-assembly-what-datastructure-to-use/54500848#54500848) by Peter Cordes.

Comment: Thank you my dear friend. Is it possible for you to edit this code for me using an array? Is it possible for you?

Comment: @AkbarNasiri That would be against the philosophy of the forum. The asker (you) has to put in a serious effort and if they encounter specific troubles they can ask a relevant question. This is what you need to do: Modify your program so it works with an array of your choosing (use whatever source of information you can find). If the program fails then you can **post a new question explaining in detail what went wrong and what you were expecting from the program**. Someone will surely provide an answer if that new question is any good...